# useReducer and userContext Typescript not working as intended

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context, use-reducer

this is my first using `useReducer` and `useContext` with `Typescript` and I'm creating a simple counter. I'm trying to update the `count` using increment and decrement dispatch but it doesn't change and no error in terminal.

Here is the link to codesandbox:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-lumiere-prw34?file=/src/state/state.ts)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using context, the `Provider` needs to be farther up the component tree than the consumer. The very top component in your code is `App`, and it immediately tries to do `useContext(CountContext)`. But since there is no provider above it, App just gets the default value of the context, which means `dispatch` is an empty function `() => {}`.

You will need to split your components up. Render the provider near the top of the tree, and then use it farther down the tree. For example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <CountContextContainer>
      <SomeChildComponent/>
    </CountContextContainer>
  );
}

function SomeChildComponent() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(CountContext);

  const increment = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: ActionType.INCREMENT,
      payload: 2
    });
  };

  const decrement = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: ActionType.DECREMENT,
      payload: 2
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Count: {state.count}</p>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```